# CSS side by side alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place the header text and the close icon on the same line but they are not aligning on the same line. I mean to say inside same div. Below is my code snippet. Could you please let me know whats the mistake i made. I am getting something like this. See below picture.

[image]

```
<div id="container-adv">
    <div id="something-else">
        <h4>Advanced Run</h4>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#orangeModalSubscription">Open</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overflow"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#container-adv {
  width: auto;
  height: auto; /* This can be any height and everything fills in */
  padding: 55px 0 0 -1px;            
}
#something-else {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  margin: -55px -24px 15px -24px;
  padding: 15px 0 1px 22px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

So my idea is to align both the text and the close icon on the same line. Can anyone suggest me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: absolute`, which is the easiest way.

```css
#container-adv {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}



#something-else{
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#something-else h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

#something-else .btn {
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-adv">
  <div id="something-else">
    <h4>Advanced Run</h4>
    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#orangeModalSubscription">Open</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overflow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for position absolute. If your 2 elements ( title and icon ) are in the same container, you can use `display:flex; justify-content:space-between; align-items:center` on that container.

`justify-content` specifies how the items should be aligned horizontally and `space-between` means 1 will be to the far left, 1 to the far right ( just like you want)

`align-items` specifies how the items should be aligned vertically and i guess you need them to be centered inside the container. They do not appear centered because the padding-top and padding-bottom of `#something-else` is not equal.

NOTE: i removed the `margin` style of `#something-else` because it made the div position strangely. Not sure why you would use negative margins.

See below:

```css
#container-adv {
  width: auto;
  height: auto; /* This can be any height and everything fills in */
  padding: 55px 0 0 -1px;            
}
#something-else {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #2196f3;
 
  padding: 15px 0 1px 22px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-adv">
    <div id="something-else">
        <h4>Advanced Run</h4>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#orangeModalSubscription">Open</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overflow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container-adv {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#something-else{
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#something-else h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.your-new-class {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 50px;
  align-self: center;
}

.your-new-class h4 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.your-new-class a {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.your-new-class h4,
.your-new-class a {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="container-adv">
  <div id="something-else">
    <div class="your-new-class">
      <h4>Advanced Run</h4>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#orangeModalSubscription"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overflow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I right in saying this is what you are looking to achieve?

You could use CSS Grid here. Granted, support is not at it's best right now but going forward it could be a good idea to begin using it in your code. It's all dependant on how far back you are willing to support.

I've placed the `<h4>` and `<a>` within the same `div`. Set the `.your-new-class` to `display: grid` and `grid-template-columns: auto 25px;`. This separates your grid into two areas. The first area is auto width, and the second fixed at 25px.

The children of that div (`<h4>` and `<a>`) have a setting of `grid-column: 1 / 2;` and `grid-column: 2 / 3;`. This is their span width. The auto area spans from point 1 (the start of the grid, from left to right) to point 2. The `<a>` spans from point 2, to point 3 (the end of the grid).

Both children use `align-self: center;` to vertically center the content.

Grid gives you a huge amount of flexibility with layouts and works brilliantly with Flexbox.

Check [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid) for full support details

And [Grid by Example](https://gridbyexample.com/). An excellent resource and starting point. I am still getting to grips with it in development but it could be an option for you.

It may not be the perfect solution and fully optimised and I have only modified your code slightly, but this shows you there are many ways to skin a cat.

*I added a Font Awesome CDN to display the 'x'. You may choose another method.